# How do I get the property value of an object in php?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom post type in wordpress that I want to get the categories for so I can list them as filter options. I used

```
$terms = get_terms(array(
'post_type' => 'leadership',
'hide_empty'=> false,
));
```

to get an object but I am having difficulty figuring out how to get anything out of it.

a chunk of the object is:

```
Array ( [0] => WP_Term Object ( [term_id] => 3 [name] => Finance
```

I want the name portions.

```
I wrote $names = $terms->name;
```

but that doesn't seem to be doing the trick.

How exactly is this handled in php?

Comment: you can `var_dump($terms);` and it will show you whats contained inside.

Comment: try with `$names = $terms[0]->name;`

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code

```
$terms = get_terms(array(
'post_type' => 'leadership',
'hide_empty'=> false,
));
 // loop the results
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    echo $term->name ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code to fetch all categories   `$names=array_column($terms, 'name');`